# Error Calling CreateEnvelope: Error Code 500. Using C# SDK

Tags: docusignapi

I am using **DocuSign eSignature API** to create Envelope but I am getting exception called **"Error Calling CreateEnvelope"**.

I have DocuSign developer free account and I have downloaded sample console c# application and ran it.

But it is throwing **"Error Calling CreateEnvelope"** and Error code is **500**

Can you please what is wrong in this?

I am trying to open the document and sign it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not provide enough information. Please use the [API request log system](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus&language=en_US&rsc_301) to isolate your Envelopes:create call (or whichever call(s) have an error response). Then EDIT your QUESTION to add the API log. Be sure to remove any private information from the log. Eg email addresses, names, etc

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No code was provided, no information about how you obtained access token.

But here is what I suggest you do - generate API logs.

The system lets you generate up to 50 API logs and you can download them and see your API calls.

Error 500 is an internal server error, and it's not your fault, it means something went wrong in DocuSign side. If you can consistently reproduce this - it's a bug that has to be fixed and the information about how to do that would be very useful to DocuSign.

Please share your code and [API logs](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-how-to-use-api-logs), and see if you can reproduce this issue.

One last thought - [Quickstart C# code](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) will just work for you and configure everything for you and you can be unblocked from your issue.